# How to add two strings alternatively?

Tags: python, list

I created a list like this:

```
a=list('Testing 123')[::2]
b=list('Testing 123')[1::2]
```

So how do I make a make a new list which adds them like they originally were?

Comment: Sorry but I am new and so I don't know how to properly use code!

Comment: Could you post your expected results so that we have a better understanding of what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> a, b
(['T', 's', 'i', 'g', '1', '3'], ['e', 't', 'n', ' ', '2'])
>>> c = [None]*(len(a)+len(b))
>>> c[::2], c[1::2] = a, b
>>> ''.join(c)
'Testing 123'
```